# Поиск одинаковых записей в текстовом массиве

Tags: perl

Как реализовать поиск одинаковых записей в текстовом массиве (@sgn_str). 
В массиве находятся подписи, надо проверить чтобы в нем не было двух и более одинаковых подписей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

т.е. необходимо удалить дубликаты?

```
my @new_list; # массив куда будут помещены "отфильтованные" значения
my @list; #исходный массив
my %seen; #хеш для работы
@new_list = grep {$_ && !$seen{$_}++} @list;
```

Comment: Нет! Надо проверить есть ли в нем одинаковые записи! 
Если есть повторения, то подписи собраны не все...
Хотя.. Далее можно сравнить количество записей в новом и старом массиве. Если совпадает, то дубликатов нет!!!

Answer (score 1):

Или так:

```
my @data = (1,2,3,3,4,4,4);
my %values;
$values{$_}++ foreach @data;
```

Comment: Соответственно, в %values и будет сколько раз встречается каждая строка:
foreach my $key ( sort keys %values ) { print "$key: $values{$key}\n"; }

Answer (score 0):

А если нужно подсчитать количество одинаковых значений?
например : 
my [[@data](/users/4262/dataman)](/users/4262/dataman) = (1,2,3,3,4,4,4);
my %values;
$values{$_}++ foreach [[@data](/users/4262/dataman)](/users/4262/dataman);
1 - 1
3 - 2
4 -3

Comment: разобрался)

Answer (score 0):

```
use List::MoreUtils "uniq";my @unique = uniq @all;
```